# Rendering GL_TRIANGLES with OpenGL in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, render, freeglut

I am trying to use a function to render a triangle with OpenGL.
The shape isn't appearing and I don't know why. I think it might be just because of the locations of the vertices.

Main method:

```
 int main() {


    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");
    Initialize();
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Initialise method:

```
 void Initialize() {
    glClearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}
```

drawTriangle function:

```
 void drawTriangle(int v1x, int v1y, int v2x, int v2y, int v3x, int v3y, int red, int green, int blue)
{
    //arguments are: "vertex 1 x coordinate", "vertex 1 y coordinate" etc
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(v1x, v1y); // v1
        glVertex2f(v2x, v2y); // v2
        glVertex2f(v3x, v3y); // v3
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}
```

Draw method:

```
void Draw() {
    drawTriangle(3.0, 2.9, 300, 300, 100, 100, 10, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, your coordinates are way off the screen. You should make yourself familiar with how GL coordinate transforms work and what `glOrtho()` does.

Answer (score 0):

Your coordinates are not fitting inside the defined ortho block

```
replace : glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0); 
with this:     glOrtho(0.0, 400.0, 0.0, 400.0, -1.0, 1.0);
```

The above is a temporary fix, it will help you understand how glOrtho works. Also, you are passing float arguments into the drawTriangle function, so you must replace all the parameters from **int to float**

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still learning, so from now on I will know.